# Mandatory fields in Wizard

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a wizard using the GUI and so my pages are all part of the UI.

Now, on one of the pages I want to make the fields mandatory. From looking into the API it appears there is a `registerField()` function which can also make sure the next button isn't available until the fields are filled in. However, that function is protected to `QWizardPage` which means I cannot set this up. Is there a way to carry out this behaviour without needing to create a new class?

I know I can create a new class but I am considering if I create even more pages then I would need to create classes for every page I have. I also thought for sucha  simple case it felt a bit like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt designed QWizardPage this way because it is page responsible for fields logic, not other classes. But if you still want to use this (bad designed) pattern, you can simple create QWizardPage wrapper with public member, that calls protected member, and use it instead of QWizardPage. Remember that pages have some logic, and it would be even better, to keep that logic separated from other classes. Also if you have some similar pages, you may reuse one class with some parameteres

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes sense from a design point of view. But the GUI allows you to set up the pages within the one class so I kind of assumed it was possible to handle what I wanted to do totally within the control also. Maybe it is set up for simple cases in the GUI.

Comment: QWizardPage is for "simple" pages only. Any extra logic should be separated

Answer (score -1):

To set a field as mandatory with registerField you just need to sets it's name ending wit '*'.

Ex:

```
QLineEdit* nameLineEdit = new QLineEdit();    
registerField("name*", nameLineEdit);
```

That way, the button to continue will be enabled  only when you write something into the nameLineEdit. Please check the documentation [QWizardField#registerField.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qwizardpage.html#registerField)